# Tridion training

Tags: core-service

I am really new to this CMS (3 days) and I need to use it for my job. Can you please advice me what type of training would I need to buy from the developers in order to learn properly how to use it?

I am a digital marketing manager and I need to update the website on a daily/weekly basis.

Comment: Not sure why you tagged your question with Core Service, it would be more beneficial if you would tag it with the version of the CMS.

Answer (score 9):

The SDL website has a nice overview of what training courses are available and to which roles these belong.

For you the role Editor seems most matching and there are a couple of eLearning courses and an on premise course available: http://www.sdl.com/trainings/list/SDL%20Web%20(Tridion)/Editor/latest/

It is also very important to understand that the foundation/basics of the Tridion CMS might not be enough for you to understand how your companies implementation actually works, since an implementation of Tridion can be very specific and customized for each client. SO it might also make sense to check out who implemented the website and if they have a specific editor training that belongs to that implementation.

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the details available [here](http://www.sdl.com/download/sdl-web-recommended-learning-tracks-per-role/116753/) I would say it would be good to get the Editor training and perhaps the business course. BluePrinting is a concept that takes a while to sink in, but once it does it makes perfect sense (believe me, it will, at one point).